# Request timeout when trying to access a specific website FROM EC2 instance

Tags: web, web-scraping, networking, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm trying to access, from inside an EC2 instance, this website:
`https://iptu.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/`
But it does not respond. From my local machine, I can access it normally.
I suspected about the region so I changed it to `sao paulo, brazil`, which is my current region, but the page still not responding.

Any idea on how to investigate further?

here are some images of the requests:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: give it a try using selenium

Comment: I'm using it @bigbounty.

Comment: @JonesSabino do you have internet access on your ec2 (I know it's a stupid question) ?   on chrome devtool / network tab can your right click/ copy as curl and paste in your ec2 shell, is it returning something ?

Comment: hi @BertrandMartel, yes I have internet access. I tried with curl, same behavior, as you can see in the image there is a first request that returns 204 (but it's analytics stuff) and then the second one is triggered and this one always ends with a timeout. I tested with selenium, curl, using the browser, etc. All the same result.  
I am almost sure that the server is blocking requests from AWS instances because I tried with another EC2/lambda in another AWS account and I had the same issue. Just need to figure out how are they doing this.

Comment: @JonesSabino the screenshot you've posted are from chrome executed on the ec2 is that right ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel yes it is.

Comment: It could be the DNS resolution that takes a long time. Try `tcpdump` and look where ti gets stuck. Examine DNS traffic. Check https://mysteries.wizardzines.com/connection-timeout.html and https://mysteries.wizardzines.com/slow-website.html. And show us the detailed Timing output from the browser if there's anything interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's possible that the server is blocking access to AWS by blacklisting aws IP range. AWS IP range can be found with the following API call: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

This documentation is about AWS IP range: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html. Using the API, you can even receive notification when AWS IP address ranges has changed.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/653987/how-do-i-block-incoming-traffic-from-amazon-aws-ips) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/223305/where-does-amazon-publish-the-range-of-ip-addresses-used-for-ec2-instances-by-re) are related